# Producer/Consumer thread example in Java using lock

Tags: java, multithreading, async-await, locking

```
public class ConsumerThreadExample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Consumer c = new Consumer();
    Thread a = new Thread(()->{while(true)c.consume();});
    Thread b = new Thread(()->{while(true)c.supply();});

    a.start();
    b.start();

    a.join();
    b.join();
    System.out.println("finish");
}
}

class Consumer{
private List<Integer> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private Condition notEnough = lock.newCondition();
private Condition toomuch = lock.newCondition();

public void consume(){
    lock.lock();
    try{
        while(buffer.isEmpty()){notEnough.await();
            System.out.println("consume waiting");}
        System.out.println(buffer);

        for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++){
            System.out.println("consume "+ buffer.remove(i));

            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("signal supply");
        toomuch.signal();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void supply(){
    lock.lock();
    try{
        while(!buffer.isEmpty()){toomuch.await();
            System.out.println("supply waiting");}
        System.out.println("Adding");
        buffer.add(1);
        buffer.add(3);
        buffer.add(5);
        System.out.println(buffer);
        System.out.println("signal consume");
        notEnough.signal();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
}
```

Hello guys, consider the code above,I want to make a practice of classical thread example which is consumer/producer.So I expect the code to fill the buffer with supply(),
then signal the consume() to consume the buffer.Whenever the buffer is empty, consume() signal the supply() again and so on.But the output seems a little bit weird. Output:

```
Adding
[1, 3, 5]
signal consume
consume waiting
[1, 3, 5]
consume 1
consume 5
signal supply
[3]
consume 3
signal supply
supply waiting
Adding
[1, 3, 5]
signal consume
consume waiting
[1, 3, 5]
consume 1
consume 5
signal supply
[3]
consume 3
signal supply
supply waiting
Adding
[1, 3, 5]
```

Why it consume 1 and 5 then signal supply()?
Where is the 3? And Why it is not in the 1,3,5 order?

Comment: Alternatively, in consumer use `remove(0)` and loop while `!isEmpty()`.  The answer explains the current fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in the first iteration

```
i = 0
buffer = [1, 3, 5]
```

And you remove 1. In the second iteration

```
i = 1
buffer = [3, 5]
```

And you remove 5. Then you exit the loop because i is now larger than the length.

Comment: Oh, that is really clear, Thank you.
So is it recommend to use iterator to walk through a list when you are removing stuff in it simultaneously?
I have tried using forEach, the output also looks weird.

Comment: You could use an iterator, or a foreach loop and clear the list after, or the exit condition should be an empty list and always remove the first element. Also I'd just use `BlockingQueue` when I want to connect 2 threads like this.